# Connection between uniform convergence in $L^1(\Omega)$ and in probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_i(x))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real random variables with $\operatorname{E}[X_i(x)]=\mu(x)\leq\infty$, for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Let's assume that we have
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\|X_i(x)\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0.$$
Is it possible to follow that
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|X_i(x)|\xrightarrow{p}0,~~\text{as}~~n\rightarrow\infty?$$

Comment: By $\|X_i(x)\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$ do you mean something like $\int |X_i(x)(\omega)| d \mu(\omega)$? And by $|X_i(x)|$ do you mean $|X_i(x)(\omega)|$?

Comment: @copper.hat : Yes, for $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\|X_i(x)\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$ that's what I mean. By $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|X_i(x)|\xrightarrow{p}0$ I mean: For all $\epsilon>0$ it holds $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}P(\{\omega\in\Omega:|X_i(x)(\omega)|>\epsilon\})~~\text{tends to}~~ 0,$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$, and $A_i(x) = \{ \omega | |X_i(x)(\omega)| > \epsilon\}$.

Since $|X_i(x)| \ge \epsilon 1_{A_i(x)} $ you have $\int |X_i(x)| \ge \epsilon P(A_i(x))$, and so $P(A_i(x)) \le {1 \over \epsilon}  \int |X_i(x)| \le  {1 \over \epsilon} \sup_x \int |X_i(x)|$.

Consequently, you have $\sup_x P(A_i(x)) \le  {1 \over \epsilon} \sup_x \int |X_i(x)|$, from which the result follows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast and understandable answer!

Comment: Delighted to help!